# How to start svg pattern from begin for two elements separately and how to setup right coordinate system?

Tags: svg

I have two thick lines and I want to apply pattern for this lines. Lines should have the same pattern, but start of drawing pattern should start from (0, 0) for each line separately. In my experiment http://jsfiddle.net/69t09wey/ patterns apply like mask. I.e pattern apply for whole svg canvas as invisible layer and where line is visible, pattern also visible.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

  <pattern id="pattern-1" width="20" height="20" x="0" y="0" patternUnits = "userSpaceOnUse" >
      <path d="M 0 0 L 20 20" fill="none" stroke="#0000ff" stroke-width="1"></path>
   </pattern>

 <g transform="scale(5)">
    <rect x="1" y="1" width="1000" height="1000"
        fill="none" stroke="blue" />

     <path d="M 1 9 L 200 9"
        fill="red" stroke="url(#pattern-1)" stroke-width="20"  />

   <path d="M 1 53 L 200 53"
        fill="red" stroke="url(#pattern-1)" stroke-width="20" />
   </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Might be easier to use `<rect x="1" y="1" width="200" height="20" fill="url(#pattern-1)" />` instead of thick line.

Answer (score 1):

If you make your lines the same.  Then move the second one by applying a transform.  That will shift the coordinate space of the pattern.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

  <pattern id="pattern-1" width="20" height="20" x="0" y="0" patternUnits = "userSpaceOnUse" >
      <path d="M 0 0 L 20 20" fill="none" stroke="#0000ff" stroke-width="1"></path>
   </pattern>

 <g transform="scale(5)">
    <rect x="1" y="1" width="1000" height="1000"
        fill="none" stroke="none" />

     <path d="M 1 9 L 200 9"
        fill="red" stroke="url(#pattern-1)" stroke-width="20"  />

     <path d="M 1 9 L 200 9" transform="translate(0,44)"
        fill="red" stroke="url(#pattern-1)" stroke-width="20" />
   </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: And pattern apply for whole svg canvas not for each line separately https://i.imgur.com/Rxtq7j9.png

Comment: Those glitches are because your line is 20 pixels wide but you are drawing the line at Y=9. So the corner of the pattern is visible. The glitch is not noticeable for the top line because it (the glitch) is off the top of the SVG.  If you change your Y coords from 9 to 10, it renders fine.